# Google Analytics jQuery track external links - _gaq & ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I want to track external links on my website with google analytics.

I inlcuded my Google Analytics Code in the header of my website:

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-XX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

I can see if someone is on my website...
After that I included is jQuery script to check if someone click an external link.

```
//Link Tracking
(function($)
{
    $('a.liexternal, a.liinternal, .wp_rp_content ul li a').click(function(e)
    {
        //Aktuelle URL
        var actual_url = window.location.href;
        //Angeklickte URL
        var clicked_url = $(this).attr('href');
        //Checken ob der Link bereits getrackt wurde (je Seitenaufruf)
        if(!e.isDefaultPrevented())
        {
            //Verhindere die Default Eventaktion (Linkklick = Seitenaufruf)
            e.preventDefault();
            //Manuelle Funktion um den Seitenaufruf nach Tracking zu bewirken
            function loadPage()
            {
                document.location = clicked_url;
            }
            //Callback Funktion um den Seitenaufruf nach Tracking durchzuführen
            //Unterschied zwischen Classic & Universal Analytics beachten!
            _gaq.push(['_set', 'hitCallback', loadPage]);

            if($(this).hasClass('liexternal'))
            {
                //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', actual_url, 'External link', clicked_url]);
                ga('send', 'event', actual_url, 'External link', clicked_url, {'hitCallback':loadPage});
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('liinternal'))
            {
                //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', actual_url, 'Internal link', clicked_url]);
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('wp_rp_title'))
            {
                //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', actual_url, 'Internal related post', clicked_url]);
            }
            else
            {
                loadPage();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If I click on a link I get following issue report:

**Error: ReferenceError: ga is not defined**

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are calling is the older Classic GA library, as evidenced by the use of the "ga.js" name, and also the "_gaq" object. However, you are trying to use the Universal Analytics method of sending events with the "ga" method (ie. ga('send','event', ....)). What you are doing is mixing the two versions up. You should consider deprecating the classic code in favour of the Universal code.

Here's where you are trying to use the ga object (where you have commented out the _gaq line):

```
if($(this).hasClass('liexternal'))
        {
            //_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', actual_url, 'External link', clicked_url]);
            ga('send', 'event', actual_url, 'External link', clicked_url, {'hitCallback':loadPage});
        }
```

Should you decide to continue using classic GA, then you should also stick to the "_gaq" method calls instead.